# Instaparse series of numbers or letters as one leaf?

Tags: clojure, ebnf, instaparse

So I've been messing around with instaparse and it's been great, however I've been trying to avoid using Regexes as a crutch and it has resulted in a bit more verbose. For the sake of keeping this readable let's just say `#'[A-z]'` is actually in the `'A'|'B'|etc` format.

```
(def myprsr (instaparse.core/parser 
  "word = (ltr | num)+; 
   <ltr> = #'[A-z]';
   <num> = '0' | '1' | '2' | '3' | '4' | '5' | '6' | '7' | '8' | '9';"))
(myprs"foo123") ;; -> [:word "f" "o" "o" "1" "2" "3"]
```

Is there any way without resorting to `#'[A-z]+'` and `#'[0-9]+` to get leaves out like `[:word "foo123"]` or `[:number "123"]` (if I had made a number toplevel rule) in order to avoid having to concatenate them as part of the post parse processing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's currently no way (besides regexes) to automatically merge those strings during the parse. I would recommend doing this concatenation in the `insta/transform` map.

There's also nothing wrong with using regexes in a case this simple. We know there isn't a possible parse we're missing out on by greedily parsing all the letters or all the numbers. Therefore regexes are acceptable (and more performant).